# How can i reference a private method from returned object in javascript?

Tags: javascript, reference, closures

Which is the best way to reference a private method from returned object in javascript? I leave you some sample code:

```
var HelloWorld = (function(){
    var hello = function(){
        console.log("hello")
    },
    return{
        addToList: function(){
            //how can i reference hello from here dynamically like:
                            //this["hello"] or this["hell" + "o"]
        }       
    }
})()
```

Comment: Have you tried it? What happened? `this['hello']();` seems fine to me...

Comment: BTW, you got a syntax error, you should have a semicolon after the `hello` function declaration, not a comma.

Comment: Not sure if you're having problems with this as well, but the `,` before the return/after the hello function should be a `;`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`hello()` is not a method.  It's just a function in a closure.  So, you can just call it from within your `addToList()` method.

If you want the `hello` function to behave like a method with `this` set to the object instance, you'd have to pass the instance to it as in this example.

```
var HelloWorld = (function(){
    var hello = function(){
        console.log("hello")
    },
    return{
        addToList: function(){
            //how can i reference hello from here dynamically like:
            hello.call(this);
        }       
    }
})()
```

---

If what you're really trying to do is to access the hello function by a string reference, you cannot easily access local variables by string name.  If you wanted to do that, you could have to put the hello function into a local object like this:

```
var HelloWorld = (function(){
    var locals = {
        hello: function(){
            console.log("hello")
        }
    };
    return{
        addToList: function(){
            //how can i reference hello from here dynamically like:
            locals["hello"].call(this);
        }       
    }
})()
```

Comment: Giving you a +1 as you posted an edit at the same time I was posting an answer, and we arrived at the same conclusion.

Comment: @JAAulde - I would say that the OP's question is not perfectly clear so I provided a couple different possible answers.

Answer (score 2):

Because the return is still inside the closure, you can just call `hello` directly. So:

```
hello();
```

To make it "dynamic", as the other answers recommend, you need to save `hello` to something. If you want to attach it to `this` instead of another object, you just need to store off a reference to `this` so you can access it later.

```
var HelloWorld = (function(){
  var self = this;
  this.hello = function(){
    console.log("hello")
  };
  return {
    addToList: function(){
        self["hello"]();
    }       
  }
})();
```

Comment: This is correct except for what I read in the OP's sample code comment. It mentions that "dynamic" access is requested, which I assume means a string is given and is used to reference the function.

Answer (score 1):

As is, you cannot reference the function `hello` "dynamically" as mentioned in the comment of your sample code. (I am assuming your definition of "dynamically" is to be given a string containing the word "hello" and somehow use it to reference the function `hello`.)

You could, however, move hello into an object and reference it off that object using square bracket notation:

```
var HelloWorld = (function () {
    var privateCode = {
        hello: function () {
            console.log('hello');
        }
    };

    return {
        addToList: function () {
            // access via `privateCode['hello']()`
        }       
    };
}());
```

Answer (score 1):

You can't use `this`, because you haven't made it a part of the object.

```
var HelloWorld = (function () {

    var hello = function () { console.log("hello"); };

    return {
        addToList : function () { hello(); }
    };

}());
```

That will work fine.

If you need to access it by using a string, then you need to make `hello`, then you have two options:

1) make a public function, which you CAN call with a string, which calls `hello`

```
return {
    command : function (string) { if (this[string]) { this[string](); },
    sayHello : function () { hello(); }
};
```

2) make a private object, which stores your methods (then you can call it with a string):

```
var private_actions = {
    hello : function () { console.log("hello"); }
};

return {
    command : function (string) {
        if (private_actions[string]) { private_actions[string](); }
    }
};
```

Answer (score 1):

Since `hello` only exists in the scope of an anonymous IIFE, you'd need to store it some intermediate object in order to be able to dynamically access `hello` from a public method:

```
var HelloWorld = (function(){
    var privates = {
        hello: function (){
            console.log("hello")
        }
    };

    return {
        addToList: function (){
            privates['hello']();
        } 
    }
})();

HelloWorld.addToList();
```

[Working Example](http://jsfiddle.net/CqZ2G/)